# Matplotlib only plotting 1 out of every 2 bars on stacked bar chart

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am trying to plot a stacked bar chart below, from `loglList`. The `'up'` or `'down'` is used to determine the colour, and the integer is the percentage that the bar represents. The array can change size, so that is why I have the `for` loops. However, when I run the code, only 1 out of 2 bars are plotted, the rest is blank spaces between them. They are also the wrong colour, despite the `if` statement.
I was wondering if anybody had any insight to why this happens? Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

loglist = [['up', 0.8519966683633334], ['down', 0.09023182638471149], ['up', 4.120008329091666], ['down', 0.09023182638471149], ['up', 0.3441534403775855], ['down', 0.089075008097728], ['up', 0.3447318495210772], ['down', 1.650779695525427], ['up', 11.537527185229743], ['down', 22.519781592707417], ['up', 14.05245014113183], ['down', 4.601823145620286], ['up', 3.8163435287585026], ['down', 2.34313544028504], ['up', 7.137568830688075], ['down', 0.7415205219564112], ['up', 3.7324742029522002], ['down', 21.91534403775855]]

width = 0.3
barDict = []

for index, plotLog in enumerate(logList):
    if(plotLog[0] == "up"):
        colour = "g"
    elif(plotLog[0] == "down"):
        colour = "r"

    bottom = 0

    for i in range(index):
        bottom = bottom + logList[i][1]


    barDict[index] = plt.bar(1, plotLog[1], width, bottom=bottom, color=colour)

plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 101, 10))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to have several typos making it hard to guess its real intent. Here is a minimal rewrite:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

logList = [['up', 0.8519966683633334], ['down', 0.09023182638471149], ['up', 4.120008329091666], ['down', 0.09023182638471149], ['up', 0.3441534403775855], ['down', 0.089075008097728], ['up', 0.3447318495210772], ['down', 1.650779695525427], ['up', 11.537527185229743], ['down', 22.519781592707417], ['up', 14.05245014113183], ['down', 4.601823145620286], ['up', 3.8163435287585026], ['down', 2.34313544028504], ['up', 7.137568830688075], ['down', 0.7415205219564112], ['up', 3.7324742029522002], ['down', 21.91534403775855]]

width = 0.3
bottom = 0
for index, plotLog in enumerate(logList):
    if (plotLog[0] == "up"):
        colour = "g"
    elif (plotLog[0] == "down"):
        colour = "r"
    plt.bar(1, plotLog[1], width, bottom=bottom, color=colour)
    bottom += plotLog[1]
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 101, 10))
plt.xticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Alternatively, you could draw the same plot with:

```py
width = 0.3
vals = np.array([plotLog[1] for plotLog in logList])
colours = ['g' if plotLog[0] == "up" else 'r' for plotLog in logList]
bars = plt.bar(np.ones_like(vals), vals, bottom=np.append(0, np.cumsum(vals[:-1])), color=colours, width=width)
```

Answer (score 0):

Several mistakes.  Try:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

logList = [['up', 0.8519966683633334], ['down', 0.09023182638471149], ['up', 4.120008329091666], ['down', 0.09023182638471149], ['up', 0.3441534403775855], ['down', 0.089075008097728], ['up', 0.3447318495210772], ['down', 1.650779695525427], ['up', 11.537527185229743], ['down', 22.519781592707417], ['up', 14.05245014113183], ['down', 4.601823145620286], ['up', 3.8163435287585026], ['down', 2.34313544028504], ['up', 7.137568830688075], ['down', 0.7415205219564112], ['up', 3.7324742029522002], ['down', 21.91534403775855]]

width = 0.3
barDict = []

for index, plotLog in enumerate(logList):
    if(plotLog[0] == "up"):
        colour = "g"
    elif(plotLog[0] == "down"):
        colour = "r"

    bottom = 0

    for i in range(index):
        bottom = bottom + logList[i][1]

    print(plotLog, plotLog[0])
    barDict.append(plt.bar(1, plotLog[1], width, bottom=bottom, color=colour))

plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 101, 10))
plt.show()
```